# "Destination address required" when attempting to send data over a SOCK_RAW socket

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, freebsd

I am trying to send a packet (not an ip packet, but an EAP-request identity), but the *send()* function is returning -1.

```
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
printf("socket: %d\n", sockfd);
struct sockaddr_in sock;
printf("creating packet\n");
char packet[27];
memcpy(packet + 0, (u_char* ) ethernet->ether_dhost, 6);
memcpy(packet + 6, (u_char* ) ethernet->ether_shost, 6);
memcpy(packet + 12, (u_char* ) ethernet + 12, 2);
memcpy(packet + 14, (u_char *)reqid, 1);
memcpy(packet + 15, (u_char *)reqid+1, 1);
memcpy(packet + 16, (u_char *)reqid+2, 4);
memcpy(packet + 20, (u_char *)reqid+6, 1);
memcpy(packet + 21, (u_char *)reqid+7, 1);
memcpy(packet + 22, (u_char *)reqid+8, 4);
memcpy(packet + 26, (u_char *)reqid+12, 1);
printf("sending packet\n");
if(send(sockfd, packet, sizeof(packet), 0) == -1)
{
     printf("packet not sent\n");
     //return;
}
```

The packet consists of an ethernet packet, and a request identity.
I know the packet is fine and every value is at the right place. but the *send()* function fails.
errno show "Destination address required" and the sockfd value is 4.
This is on FreeBSD by the way.
Thanks
**EDIT:** I don't have the IP address of the destination. I only have its MAC address.

Comment: What is `errno`? Is `sockfd` valid? ISTR `SOCK_RAW` requires root

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Destination address required.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit also, yes the **sockfd** is valid. its value is 4. and I am in the root user.

Comment: Okay. Would be good to show all that detail in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After these answers and further readings, i figured that there is no way to use socket in FreeBSD for my purpose.
So now I'm using `libpcap` for this. Using the `pcap_sendPacket()` I can send packets with the ethernet address.
Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2):

From the manpage:

> The send() call may be used only when the socket is in a connected state (so that the intended recipient is known).

I believe you want `sendto`, not `send`.

Comment: But the problem is `sendto` needs destination IP address. I don't have that. I only have its MAC address.

Comment: @ipinlnd: Both do. The only difference is that `send` takes the destination from the connection context, which you don't have here. You should be able to use port=0 and address=NULL, though you may also need to create the socket with the flag `IP_HDRINCL` so the API doesn't prepend an IP header of its own. Which guide are you using?

Comment: Oh, or you could use the destination MAC address per https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/

Comment: I can't exactly use that, but it gave me some idea. thanks :) I'll see what else i can find.

Answer (score 1):

When using raw sockets you don't specify the Ethernet address. Raw sockets let you create IP datagrams in which you can send just the payload and the network stack will configure the IP header or you can also specify the IP header if the IP_HDRINCL socket option is enabled. Here you cannot specify an Ethernet address. Read: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html

If you don't have the IP address and only have the Ethernet address, this is another problem that you need to solve in different ways.

First, you will need to use Packet sockets http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html and send an Ethernet frame to the other node.

The problem is that the other node will pass that frame to the upper layer (the device driver will do this). There, if the upper layer doesn't see its IP address it will drop the message. So you may want to send a RARP message and expect the other node responds you passing its IP address. Other possibility is that you implement your own layer 2 protocol ...